# Date picker format

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I use Wordpress, and I bought a template (about listings). 
I tried to customize it as I want to change the format of the date, because when I click on the date picker and I choose a date the format is:

```
"01 January 2017"
```

And I want

```
 "01/01/2017"
```

So I just want to customize it, but I can't.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUVzs.png)

Comment: Get in touch with the company that sold you the date picker template. They'll be able to advise you.

Comment: Mmm thank you, but you can't do something ? maybe

Comment: No, because I can't see any of your code. They'll be using javascript to generate the date. Not CSS. So you need to find out how to get certain date formats in Javascript and then see if you can understand their javascript files to replace their date generator code. You may also need to `un-minify` them (if that's possible).

Comment: Unless you show us your code here, no one here can really help you. It's like asking us to paint what you can see, we can't see it so we can't paint it.

Comment: Asking the people you bought it from is indeed likely your best bet but in case it helps you DIY it, looks like they've used jQuery UI's date picker. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: You may want to read How to create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MVCE).

Comment: Using a format like 01/01/2017 on the web is not a good idea as it's not clear which token designates the month and which the day. A format that uses a word for the month is much preferred, e.g. 1 Jan 2017 or Jan 1 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Look here when I inspect the field form I find this : [Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/283Hh.png)

and when I change the type of the input it works : [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbror.png)

But this is just in browser, I can't do it in the files of the template